# How can I simplify code generation at runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, assembly, x86

I'm working on a piece of software which generates assembler code at runtime. For instance,
here's a very simple function which generates assembler code for calling the [`GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) function (for the Win64 ABI):

```
void genGetCurrentProcess( char *codePtr, FARPROC addressForGetCurrentProcessFunction )
{
#ifdef _WIN64
  // mov rax, addressForGetCurrentProcessFunction
  *codePtr++ = 0x48
  *codePtr++ = 0xB8;
  *((FARPROC *)codePtr)++ = addressForGetCurrentProcessFunction;

  // call rax
  *codePtr++ = 0xFF;
  *codePtr++ = 0xD0;
#else
  // mov eax, addressForGetCurrentProcessfunction
  *codePtr++ = 0xB8;
  *((FARPROC *)codePtr)++ = addressForGetCurrentProcessFunction;

  // call eax
  *codePtr++ = 0xFF;
  *codePtr++ = 0xD0;
#endif
}
```

Usually I'd use inline assembler, but alas - this doesn't seem to be possible with the 64bit MSVC compilers anymore. While I'm at it - this code should work with MSVC6 up to MSVC10 and also MinGW. There are many more functions like `genGetCurrentProcess`, they all emit assembler code and many of them get function pointers to be called passed as arguments.

The annoying thing about this is that modifying this code is error-prone and we've got to take care of ABI-specific things manually (for instance, reserving 32 bytes stack space before calling functions for register spilling).

So my question is - can I simplify this code for generating assembler code at runtime? My hope was that I could somehow write the assembler code directly (possibly in an external file which is then assembled using `ml`/`ml64`) but it's not clear to me how this would work if some of the bytes in the assembled code are only known at runtime (the `addressForGetcurrentProcessFunction` value in the above example, for instance). Maybe it's possible to assemble some code but assign 'labels' to certain locations in the code so that I can easily modify the code at runtime and then copy it into my buffer?

Comment: this is not inline-assembly, it's inline machine code!

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why not just call GetCurrentProcess() directly from your C code?

Comment: @user9876: I'm patching code in a remote (suspended) process; this program achieves a similiar affect as `LD_PRELOAD` on Unix system.

Comment: For anything beyond trivial patching, if you can use "clean" methods, you're usually better off injecting a DLL and have the DLL overwrite procedure entry points or similar. Of course not always possible (exploits, fixing bugs in protected code, et cetera) - but it's so much less headache.

Comment: @snemarch: Absolutely agreed; I use various other injection techiniques in other places. However, in this particular software, a key feature is that the code injected into the process gets executed *before any code in the target application starts running* (excluding `DllMain` implementations of DLLs which were already loaded). In fact, the code I'm injecting is a `GetProcAddress`/`LoadLibrary` sequence - the heavy lifting is done by the DLL which is loaded.

Comment: @Frerich: check the XCOM bugfix loader at the 'exports' part of http://f0dder.reteam.org/ for an alternate solution :)

Comment: snemarch: The XCOM bugfix loader is quite similiar to the program I'm working on, except that mine works a bit more generically (it doesn't have the entry point address hardcoded, and it works for 32/64 bit processes alike). I had to smile when I saw the bin2o program on that page, because I wrote exactly the same for ELF (it's called "elfrc") once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit). It is a C++ library for runtime code-generation. Supports x64 and probably most of the existing extensions (FPU, MMX, 3dNow, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSE4). Its interface resembles assembly syntax and it encodes the instructions correctly for you.

Comment: +1 - asmjit looks interesting, and I wasn't aware of that yet! Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

You could depend on a real assembler to do the work for you - one that generates binary output is obviously the best. Consider looking at [yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net/) or [fasm](http://www.flatassembler.net/) (there's some posts on the fasm forums about doing a DLL version, so you don't have to write a temporary assembly file, launch external process, and read output file back, but I dunno if it's been updated for later versions).

This might be overkill if your needs are relatively simple, though. I'd consider doing a C++ Assembler class supporting just the mnemonics you need, along with some helper functions like `GeneratePrologue`, `GenerateEpilogue`, `InstructionPointerRelativeAddress` and such. This would allow you to write pseudo-assembly, and having the helper functions take care of 32/64bit issues.

Comment: Factoring the machine code out into a dedicated assembler file and then letting a real assembler do the translation would be my preferred solution. However, note that my machine code is not static - the values put into registers are only known at runtime, so I have to be able to "patch" the code generated by the assembler at runtime to fix up values. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Do you need to run the generated code from the same process that generates it, or do you need to produce output for another process (shellcode injection, whatever)?

Comment: There is. Store the offsets of the locations that need patching in a table (at the beginning or end of your generated asm source code), have the instructions that need patching use some dummy values. Then patch the resultant binary using that table. Or better yet put those runtime values into a table and have your asm code fetch them from that table.

Comment: @snemarch: The generated code is going to be executed in another process.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, that's the kind of solution I was hoping for. However, I'm not sure how I could store the offsets of the locations that need patching without hardcoding their positions (but rather have the assembler compute the positions).

Comment: You write your code like this: `mov eax, 0x12345678 ;  addressForGetCurrentProcessfunction`, `patch1: call eax`, `; other code...`, `patchtable dd patch1 - 4`, `patchtablesize dd $ - patchtable`. The last dword (patchtablesize) will tell you the size of the patch table with offsets. You'll extract them, e.g. `patch1 - 4` will point to `0x12345678`, which you'll overwrite with &GetCurrentProcess. You will probably need to make the patch table more complex and describe what type of thing its every element is patching. But that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract away some instruction encoding, calling convention and CPU-mode-related details by writing some helper functions and macros.

You can even create a small assembler that would assemble pseudo-asm-code numerically encoded and contained in an array into runnable code, e.g. starting with input like this:

```
UINT32 blah[] =
{
  mov_, ebx_, dwordPtr_, edi_, plus_, eax_, times8_, plus_, const_, 0xFEDCBA98,
  call_, dwordPtr_, ebx_,
};
```

But it's a lot of work to get this done and done right. For something simpler, just create helper functions/macros, essentially doing what you have already done, but hiding some nasty details from the user.

Comment: Unfortunately assembler statements don't map to bytes like that (and using an `UINT32` array is certainly not correct, it should be `UINT8` or similiar).

Comment: What prevents you from mapping them? Just define an enumeration with a few hundred elements in it. No doubt, the resultant enum constants will need more than 8 bits per constant if you have more than 256 of them, but there will be nothing wrong in storing them in an array of UINT32s, will there? UINT32 is handy since it lets you embed constants (like in `mov eax, -123` and in `mov byte ptr [ebx+0x123], 'a'`) easily as -123, 0x123, 'a'. You've probably missed the point. This array will not contain instructions ready for execution, it will contain stuff to be parsed and compiled by extra code.

Comment: @Alex, his point was that x86/x64 assembler instructions greatly vary in size and encoding format. It is not a matter of simple mapping and embedding consts in your map defeats the purpose.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: They vary, so you write a relatively simple assembler to take care of that and to translate a sequence of constants like `call_, dwordPtr_, ebx_` into fully encoded instructions ready for execution. Such an assembler is about 2KLOC, with 1KLOC for the code and 1KLOC for the enums and tables describing general purpose instructions (more for FPU/SSE/etc).

Comment: I understand what you mean but I think you are wrong about the "simple" part (well, you did say "relatively", so it's just a matter of comparison :))

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do is build a set of abstractions that represent the generation of the elements of the machine instructions of interest, and then compose calls to get the instructions/addressing modes you want.  If you generate a wide variety of code, you can end up encoding the whole instruction set this way.

Then to generate a MOV instruction, you can write code that looks like:

```
ObjectCodeEmitMovRegister32ScaledRegister32OffsetRegister32(EAX,EDX,4,-LowerBound*4,ESP);
```

You can tell I like long names. (At least I never forget what they do.)

Here's some bits of a code generator supporting this that I implemented in C a long time ago.  This covers kind of the hardest part, which is generation of MOD and SIB bytes. Following this style one can implement as much of the instruction set as one likes.   This example is only for x32, so OP will have to extend and modify accordingly.  The definition of the MOV instruction generator is down at the end.

```
#define Register32T enum Register32Type
enum Register32Type {EAX=0,ECX=1,EDX=2,EBX=3,ESP=4,EBP=5,ESI=6,EDI=7};

inline
byte ObjectCodeEmitModRM32Register32(Register32T Register32,Register32T BaseRegister32)
// Send ModRM32Bytes for register-register mode to object file
{  byte ModRM32Byte=0xC0+Register32*0x8+BaseRegister32;
   ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
   return ModRM32Byte;
}

inline
byte ObjectCodeEmitModRM32Direct(Register32T Register32)
// Send ModRM32Bytes for direct address mode to object file
{  byte ModRM32Byte=Register32*0x8+0x05;
   ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
   return ModRM32Byte;
}

inline
void ObjectCodeEmitSIB(Register32T ScaledRegister32,
           natural Scale,
           Register32T BaseRegister32)
// send SIB byte to object file
// Note: Use ESP for ScaledRegister32 to disable scaling; only useful when using ESP for BASE.
{  if (ScaledRegister32==ESP && BaseRegister32!=ESP) CompilerFault(31);
   if      (Scale==1) ObjectCodeEmitByte((byte)(0x00+ScaledRegister32*0x8+BaseRegister32));
   else if (Scale==2) ObjectCodeEmitByte((byte)(0x40+ScaledRegister32*0x8+BaseRegister32));
   else if (Scale==4) ObjectCodeEmitByte((byte)(0x80+ScaledRegister32*0x8+BaseRegister32));
   else if (Scale==8) ObjectCodeEmitByte((byte)(0xC0+ScaledRegister32*0x8+BaseRegister32));
   else CompilerFault(32);
} 

inline
byte ObjectCodeEmitModRM32OffsetRegister32(Register32T Register32,
                       integer Offset,
                       Register32T BaseRegister32)
// Send ModRM32Bytes for indexed address mode to object file
// Returns 1st byte of ModRM32 for possible use in EmittedPushRM32 peephole optimization
{ byte ModRM32Byte;
  if (Offset==0 && BaseRegister32!=EBP)
 {  ModRM32Byte=0x00+Register32*0x8+BaseRegister32;
    ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
    if (BaseRegister32==ESP) ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ESP,1,ESP);
 }
  else if (Offset>=-128 && Offset<=127)
       { ModRM32Byte=0x40+Register32*0x8+BaseRegister32;
     ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
     if (BaseRegister32==ESP) ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ESP,1,ESP);
     ObjectCodeEmitByte((byte)Offset);
       }
  else { // large offset
     ModRM32Byte=0x80+Register32*0x8+BaseRegister32;
     ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
     if (BaseRegister32==ESP) ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ESP,1,ESP);
     ObjectCodeEmitDword(Offset);
   }
  return ModRM32Byte;
}

inline
byte ObjectCodeEmitModRM32OffsetScaledRegister32(Register32T Register32,
                         integer Offset,
                         Register32T ScaledRegister32,
                         natural Scale)
// Send ModRM32Bytes for indexing by a scaled register with no base register to object file
// Returns 1st byte of ModRM32 for possible use in EmittedPushRM32 peephole optimization
{ byte ModRM32Byte=0x00+Register32*0x8+ESP;
  ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte); // MOD=00 --> SIB does disp32[index]
  ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ScaledRegister32,Scale,EBP);
  ObjectCodeEmitDword(Offset);
  return ModRM32Byte;
}

inline
byte ObjectCodeEmitModRM32ScaledRegister32OffsetRegister32(Register32T Register32,
                               Register32T ScaledRegister32,
                               natural Scale,
                               integer Offset,
                               Register32T BaseRegister32)
// Send ModRM32Bytes for indexed address mode to object file
// Returns 1st byte of ModRM32 for possible use in EmittedPushRM32 peephole optimization
// If Scale==0, leave scale and scaled register out of the computation
{ byte ModRM32Byte;
  if (Scale==0) ObjectCodeEmitModRM32OffsetRegister32(Register32,Offset,BaseRegister32);
  else if (Offset==0 && BaseRegister32!=EBP)
 {  ModRM32Byte=0x00+Register32*0x8+ESP;
    ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
    ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ScaledRegister32,Scale,BaseRegister32);
 }
  else if (Offset>=-128 && Offset<=127)
       { ModRM32Byte=0x40+Register32*0x8+ESP;
     ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
     ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ScaledRegister32,Scale,BaseRegister32);
     ObjectCodeEmitByte((byte)Offset);
       }
  else { // large offset
     ModRM32Byte=0x80+Register32*0x8+ESP;
     ObjectCodeEmitByte(ModRM32Byte);
     ObjectCodeEmitSIB(ScaledRegister32,Scale,BaseRegister32);
     ObjectCodeEmitDword(Offset);
   }
  return ModRM32Byte;
}

inline
void ObjectCodeEmitLeaRegister32OffsetRegister32ScaledPlusBase32(
               Register32T Register32Destination,
                           integer Offset,
                           Register32T Register32Source,
               natural Scale, // 1,2,4 or 8
               Register32T Base)
// send "LEA Register32,offset[Register32*Scale+Base]" to object file
{ ObjectCodeEmitLeaOpcode();
  ObjectCodeEmitModRM32ScaledRegister32OffsetRegister32(
    Register32Destination,Register32Source,Scale,Offset,Base);
}

inline
void ObjectCodeEmitMovRegister32ScaledRegister32OffsetRegister32(Register32T DestinationRegister32,
                               Register32T ScaledRegister32,
                               natural Scale,
                               integer Offset,
                               Register32T BaseRegister32)
// Emit Mov R32 using scaled index addressing
{  ObjectCodeEmitMovRegister32Opcode();
   ObjectCodeEmitModRM32ScaledRegister32OffsetRegister32(DestinationRegister32,
                             ScaledRegister32,
                             Scale,
                             Offset,
                             BaseRegister32);
}
```